# How do I set an imagebutton's alpha back to normal if an int is higher than -1?

Tags: android, int, imagebutton, alpha

I'm trying to make an `Imagebutton` greyed out, if an `int` equals `-1`. And if `int` is higher than `-1` the `Imagebutton` should be set to normal. I used `imgbtn.setImageAlpha(0x3F);` to set my `img button` to grey. The index is changed by two buttons: one goes +1 (-1,0,1) and the other goes previous. So if I click on next -1 is then 0 and if I click the previous button 0 becomes -1.

the code:

```
 if (index == -1){
                imagebtn.setImageAlpha(0x3F);
            }

            if (index > -1){
                imagebtn.setImageAlpha(0xFF);
            }
```

Edit: When using this code: If index equals -1 it turns gray, but when index is higher than -1 (0 or 1,2,3...) the imagebutton is still greyed out. 
What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageAlpha(int))

> `setImageAlpha` takes a value between 0(transparent) and 255(opaque). Try to set 255 as imageAlpha when `index > -1` and around 100 when `index == -1`

```
if (index == -1){
    imagebtn.setImageAlpha(100); // change as you need
}

if (index > -1){
    imagebtn.setImageAlpha(255);
}
```

Comment: using this code the button turned gray when the index is -1, button when it's not -1 the button is still grayed out.

Comment: Where do you have this logic? and also are you sure index is greater than -1

Comment: I have this in `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` or in `Oncreate` and with greater than -1 I mean (0,1,2,3...)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your sembols like this :

```
 if (index <= -1){
            imagebtn.setImageAlpha(0xFF);

        }
```

You are using wrong conditions. -1 is the biggest number of negative. So that; Your condition turns "false". But if you do like my answer. Your condition turns "true". And your code will works.

Comment: using this code the button turned gray when the index is -1, button when it's not -1 the button is still grayed out.

Comment: Because ; your "0xFF" is opaque.I checked your values by putting them another place. "0x3F" is half opaque and works.

Comment: where did you put them ? I put them in onCreate

Comment: sorry i am late. imagebtn.setImageAlpha(0x3F); i tried 0x3F instead of OxFF. That is between () .

Comment: 0x3F will make it gray, 0xFF will make the imgbuton back to normal. And I want to make it (0x3F) if the index is -1 and if it is greater than -1 (for example 0,1,2...) it should be (0xFF)

Comment: Okey. Check my code again. It works that what you said

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195822/discussion-between-creesch-2-0-and-berkay-isikoglu).

Comment: Of course. Just wait for me 6 minutes. I will be there.